# Chisel3: Vec indexWhere expected Bool, actual Any

Tags: chisel

In Chisel, I have a Vec of Bools coming into a module. I would like to know the index of the first False which occurs.

To obtain this, I tried to use the following:

```scala
val faultIndex = Wire(UInt)

faultIndex := comparison.indexWhere(x:Bool => x === false.B)
```

When I put this in, an error was highlighted:

```
Unspecified value parameters: from: Int
Type mismatch, expected Bool => Bool, actual: Bool => Any
Type mismatch, expected Bool => Boolean, actual: Bool => Any
Cannot resolve symbol x
Cannot resolve symbol x
```

What is the proper way to use this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 minor syntax issues here:

```scala
val faultIndex = Wire(UInt())
```

Note the `()` after `UInt`. You can think about this as constructing a fresh type object rather than pointing to the static object called `UInt`.

There are a few ways to express the `indexWhere`:

```scala
faultIndex := comparison.indexWhere((x: Bool) => x === false.B) // Note parentheses
// or
faultIndex := comparison.indexWhere(x => x === false.B) // Type is inferred
// or
faultIndex := comparison.indexWhere(_ === false.B) // underscore shorthand
// alternatively
faultIndex := comparison.indexWhere(x => !x) // !x is equivalent to x === false.B
// or
faultIndex := comparison.indexWhere(!_)      // More underscore shorthand
```

Executable example: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/uHCX5wxgSzu6wXqa9OJdRA

Comment: Thank you for the insight! After changing the Uint to UInt() it became much more clear. If you dont mind, could you maybe explain what the point of the complicated input to the IndexWhere function is? I'm not familiar with languages other than C, so this programming technique isnt familiar to me.

Comment: `indexWhere` is a "higher-order function" (HOF), ie. the argument is a function itself (aka a lambda). Trying to explain their utility in a SO comment is a tough task, so I'd just recommend reading up them. While they're a bit alien coming from C, they're increasingly common in modern programming languages: eg. Swift, Rust, Java, JavaScript, Python.